# GROUP BY SUM CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, case

I want to group by account number, but I am running into problems if I get multiple RATE_CD's for an account - I get a NONCOMPLIANT_CNT of 2, but I want it to be only 1 per account even if there is more than 1 RATE_CD.

Below is the SQL I'm playing around with, any ideas on how I can return the NONCOMPLIANT_CNT per account, and not roll up the count if there is more than 1 RATE_CD?

```
SELECT ID
    ,ACCOUNT_NBR SUM(CASE 
            WHEN GROUP_CD = 'RED'
                AND TYPE_CD IN ('CHK')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'COMPLIANT_CNT'
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN GROUP_CD = 'RED'
                AND TYPE_CD IN (
                    'CN'
                    ,'RN'
                    )
                AND RATE_CD <> 'BLK'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'NONCOMPLIANT_CNT'
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN GROUP_CD = 'RED'
                AND TYPE_CD IN (
                    'CN'
                    ,'RN'
                    ,'CHK'
                    )
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'TOTAL_CNT'
FROM DETAIL
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_LOOKUP ACCOUNT_NBR = ACCOUNT_NBR
GROUP BY ID
    ,ACCOUNT_NBR
    ,RATE_CD
```

Comment: `CASE` **Expression**. `Case` (`Switch`) statements do not exist in SQL Server. `CASE` expressions return a scalar value, not a boolean result.

Comment: Seems like what you're actually after is `COUNT(DISTINCT ... Account_NBR` not  `SUM(...1)`.

Comment: Also, why a **`LEFT JOIN`** on `ACCOUNT_NBR=ACCOUNT_NBR`? When is `ACCOUNT_NBR` *not* going to equal the value of `ACCOUNT_NBR`? Just use `CROSS JOIN RATE_LOOKUP` instead. (Unless `RATE_LOOKUP` isn't going to contain rows for some reason?)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 1 instead of how many actual, change your SUM() to MAX().  So if they have 5 entries, it would still show as at least 1, otherwise will be 0 for the given column aggregate.